# Pandas: Upload to a mysql table

Tags: python, mysql, pandas

I have the following dataframe, that is called `ind_concat`:

[image]

I am trying to upload it to a mysql table using the following:

```
ind_concat.to_sql('indicators_correspondances', engine, if_exists='replace', index=True, 
                  index_label='common_names')
```

The formula above doesn't work because the index is a blob text , and receive `mysql error 1170 : key specification without a key length`

If I turn the index into a column and upload with `index=False`, it does work:

```
concat_ind['index'] = ind_concat.index
ind_concat.to_sql('indicators_correspondances', engine, if_exists='replace', index=False)
```

But i don't like that the column is then the last one and have a header such as ('index', '') because of the multiindex.

So I would rather use the `dtype` argument and give a lenght to the text of the index. I tried:

```
ind_concat.to_sql('indicators_correspondances', engine, if_exists='replace', index=True, 
                  index_label='common_names', dtype = {'common_names':'Text'})
```

I also tried giving dtype the values `{'common_names':'Text(25)'}` or  `{'common_names':'String(25)'}` (which I found on the page: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/type_basics.html#generic-types) but they didnt work either.

Would anyone have **a working example of assigning such a text dtype with length to a mysql column, using the sqlalchemy types**?

Here below the data to reconstruct the dataframe:

```
dikt={('investingcom', 'original_name'): {'CPI Ex Food and Energy MoM': 'Core CPI (MoM)', 'PCE Core MoM': 'Core PCE Price Index (MoM)', 'Construction Spending MoM': nan, 'Personal Spending': 'Personal Spending (MoM)', 'Existing Home Sales MoM': 'Existing Home Sales (MoM)', 'ISM Non-Manufacturing PMI': 'ISM Non-Manufacturing PMI', 'Pending Home Sales MoM': 'Pending Home Sales (MoM)', 'FHFA House Price Index MoM': nan, 'Housing Starts': 'Housing Starts', 'S&P/CaseShiller 20-City Index NSA': 'S&P;/CS HPI Composite - 20 n.s.a. (YoY)', 'Employment Cost Index': 'Employment Cost Index (QoQ)', 'New Home Sales': 'New Home Sales', 'Business Inventories MoM': 'Business Inventories (MoM)', 'Initial Jobless Claims': 'Initial Jobless Claims', 'Empire Manufacturing': nan, 'Import Price Index MoM': 'Import Price Index (MoM)', 'ADP Employment Change': 'ADP Nonfarm Employment Change', 'Nonfarm Payrolls': 'Nonfarm Payrolls', 'Capacity Utilization': nan, 'Durable Goods Orders': 'Durable Goods Orders (MoM)', 'Markit Composite PMI': 'Markit Composite PMI', 'Factory Orders': 'Factory Orders (MoM)', 'Building Permits': 'Building Permits', 'Total Net TIC Flows': 'TIC Net Long-Term Transactions', 'Chicago PMI': 'Chicago PMI', 'FOMC Rate Decision': 'Fed Interest Rate Decision', 'Existing Home Sales': 'Existing Home Sales', 'GDP Price Index': 'GDP Price Index (QoQ)'}, ('ft', 'original_name'): {'CPI Ex Food and Energy MoM': 'CPI (ex Food & Energy) % m/m', 'PCE Core MoM': 'Core PCE Price Index % m/m', 'Construction Spending MoM': 'Construction Spending % m/m', 'Personal Spending': nan, 'Existing Home Sales MoM': nan, 'ISM Non-Manufacturing PMI': 'ISM Non-Manufacturing index', 'Pending Home Sales MoM': 'Pending Home Sales % m/m', 'FHFA House Price Index MoM': 'FHFA House Price Index % m/m', 'Housing Starts': nan, 'S&P/CaseShiller 20-City Index NSA': 'S&P Case-Shiller Home Price % y/y', 'Employment Cost Index': 'Employment cost index % q/q', 'New Home Sales': 'New Home Sales k', 'Business Inventories MoM': 'Business inventories % m/m', 'Initial Jobless Claims': 'Initial Claims k', 'Empire Manufacturing': 'Empire State Survey index', 'Import Price Index MoM': nan, 'ADP Employment Change': nan, 'Nonfarm Payrolls': 'Non-farm Payrolls k', 'Capacity Utilization': 'Capacity utilisation %', 'Durable Goods Orders': 'Durable goods orders % m/m', 'Markit Composite PMI': nan, 'Factory Orders': nan, 'Building Permits': 'Building Permits k', 'Total Net TIC Flows': nan, 'Chicago PMI': 'Chicago PMI index', 'FOMC Rate Decision': 'FOMC Rate Decision', 'Existing Home Sales': 'Existing home sales mn', 'GDP Price Index': nan}, ('investingcom', 'importance'): {'CPI Ex Food and Energy MoM': 3.0, 'PCE Core MoM': 2.0, 'Construction Spending MoM': nan, 'Personal Spending': 2.0, 'Existing Home Sales MoM': 2.0, 'ISM Non-Manufacturing PMI': 3.0, 'Pending Home Sales MoM': 3.0, 'FHFA House Price Index MoM': nan, 'Housing Starts': 2.0, 'S&P/CaseShiller 20-City Index NSA': 2.0, 'Employment Cost Index': 2.0, 'New Home Sales': 3.0, 'Business Inventories MoM': 2.0, 'Initial Jobless Claims': 2.0, 'Empire Manufacturing': nan, 'Import Price Index MoM': 2.0, 'ADP Employment Change': 3.0, 'Nonfarm Payrolls': 3.0, 'Capacity Utilization': nan, 'Durable Goods Orders': 2.0, 'Markit Composite PMI': 2.0, 'Factory Orders': 2.0, 'Building Permits': 3.0, 'Total Net TIC Flows': 2.0, 'Chicago PMI': 2.0, 'FOMC Rate Decision': 3.0, 'Existing Home Sales': 3.0, 'GDP Price Index': 2.0}, ('bloomberg', 'importance'): {'CPI Ex Food and Energy MoM': 76.0976, 'PCE Core MoM': 59.756100000000004, 'Construction Spending MoM': 79.674800000000005, 'Personal Spending': 85.365899999999996, 'Existing Home Sales MoM': 51.219499999999996, 'ISM Non-Manufacturing PMI': 76.422799999999995, 'Pending Home Sales MoM': 77.235799999999998, 'FHFA House Price Index MoM': 69.918700000000001, 'Housing Starts': 89.430899999999994, 'S&P/CaseShiller 20-City Index NSA': 52.845500000000001, 'Employment Cost Index': 74.796700000000001, 'New Home Sales': 90.243899999999996, 'Business Inventories MoM': nan, 'Initial Jobless Claims': 98.373999999999995, 'Empire Manufacturing': 82.113799999999998, 'Import Price Index MoM': 78.0488, 'ADP Employment Change': 82.9268, 'Nonfarm Payrolls': nan, 'Capacity Utilization': 62.032499999999999, 'Durable Goods Orders': 92.682900000000004, 'Markit Composite PMI': 70.0, 'Factory Orders': 86.991900000000001, 'Building Permits': 62.601599999999998, 'Total Net TIC Flows': 65.040700000000001, 'Chicago PMI': 81.300799999999995, 'FOMC Rate Decision': 97.561000000000007, 'Existing Home Sales': 87.804900000000004, 'GDP Price Index': 77.398399999999995}, ('bloomberg', 'original_name'): {'CPI Ex Food and Energy MoM': 'CPI Ex Food and Energy MoM', 'PCE Core MoM': 'PCE Core MoM', 'Construction Spending MoM': 'Construction Spending MoM', 'Personal Spending': 'Personal Spending', 'Existing Home Sales MoM': 'Existing Home Sales MoM', 'ISM Non-Manufacturing PMI': 'ISM Non-Manf. Composite', 'Pending Home Sales MoM': 'Pending Home Sales MoM', 'FHFA House Price Index MoM': 'FHFA House Price Index MoM', 'Housing Starts': 'Housing Starts', 'S&P/CaseShiller 20-City Index NSA': 'S&P/CaseShiller 20-City Index NSA', 'Employment Cost Index': 'Employment Cost Index', 'New Home Sales': 'New Home Sales', 'Business Inventories MoM': nan, 'Initial Jobless Claims': 'Initial Jobless Claims', 'Empire Manufacturing': 'Empire Manufacturing', 'Import Price Index MoM': 'Import Price Index MoM', 'ADP Employment Change': 'ADP Employment Change', 'Nonfarm Payrolls': nan, 'Capacity Utilization': 'Capacity Utilization', 'Durable Goods Orders': 'Durable Goods Orders', 'Markit Composite PMI': 'Markit US Composite PMI', 'Factory Orders': 'Factory Orders', 'Building Permits': 'Building Permits', 'Total Net TIC Flows': 'Total Net TIC Flows', 'Chicago PMI': 'Chicago Purchasing Manager', 'FOMC Rate Decision': 'FOMC Rate Decision (Upper Bound)', 'Existing Home Sales': 'Existing Home Sales', 'GDP Price Index': 'GDP Price Index'}, ('index', ''): {'CPI Ex Food and Energy MoM': 'CPI Ex Food and Energy MoM', 'PCE Core MoM': 'PCE Core MoM', 'Construction Spending MoM': 'Construction Spending MoM', 'Personal Spending': 'Personal Spending', 'Existing Home Sales MoM': 'Existing Home Sales MoM', 'ISM Non-Manufacturing PMI': 'ISM Non-Manufacturing PMI', 'Pending Home Sales MoM': 'Pending Home Sales MoM', 'FHFA House Price Index MoM': 'FHFA House Price Index MoM', 'Housing Starts': 'Housing Starts', 'S&P/CaseShiller 20-City Index NSA': 'S&P/CaseShiller 20-City Index NSA', 'Employment Cost Index': 'Employment Cost Index', 'New Home Sales': 'New Home Sales', 'Business Inventories MoM': 'Business Inventories MoM', 'Initial Jobless Claims': 'Initial Jobless Claims', 'Empire Manufacturing': 'Empire Manufacturing', 'Import Price Index MoM': 'Import Price Index MoM', 'ADP Employment Change': 'ADP Employment Change', 'Nonfarm Payrolls': 'Nonfarm Payrolls', 'Capacity Utilization': 'Capacity Utilization', 'Durable Goods Orders': 'Durable Goods Orders', 'Markit Composite PMI': 'Markit Composite PMI', 'Factory Orders': 'Factory Orders', 'Building Permits': 'Building Permits', 'Total Net TIC Flows': 'Total Net TIC Flows', 'Chicago PMI': 'Chicago PMI', 'FOMC Rate Decision': 'FOMC Rate Decision', 'Existing Home Sales': 'Existing Home Sales', 'GDP Price Index': 'GDP Price Index'}, ('ft', 'importance'): {'CPI Ex Food and Energy MoM': 'Medium', 'PCE Core MoM': 'Medium', 'Construction Spending MoM': 'Medium', 'Personal Spending': nan, 'Existing Home Sales MoM': nan, 'ISM Non-Manufacturing PMI': 'High', 'Pending Home Sales MoM': 'Medium', 'FHFA House Price Index MoM': 'Medium', 'Housing Starts': nan, 'S&P/CaseShiller 20-City Index NSA': 'Medium', 'Employment Cost Index': 'Medium', 'New Home Sales': 'Medium', 'Business Inventories MoM': 'Medium', 'Initial Jobless Claims': 'Medium', 'Empire Manufacturing': 'Medium', 'Import Price Index MoM': nan, 'ADP Employment Change': nan, 'Nonfarm Payrolls': 'High', 'Capacity Utilization': 'Medium', 'Durable Goods Orders': 'Medium', 'Markit Composite PMI': nan, 'Factory Orders': nan, 'Building Permits': 'Medium', 'Total Net TIC Flows': nan, 'Chicago PMI': 'Medium', 'FOMC Rate Decision': 'High', 'Existing Home Sales': 'Medium', 'GDP Price Index': nan}}
pd.DataFrame(dikt, columns=[('investingcom', 'importance'), ('investingcom', 'original_name'), ('bloomberg', 'importance'), ('bloomberg', 'original_name'), ('ft', 'importance'), ('ft', 'original_name'), ('index', '')])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the following will work (tested with MySQL 5.1), but it'll produce terrible column names:

```
from sqlalchemy import types, create_engine

df.rename_axis('common_names') \
  .to_sql('zzz', engine, index=True, index_label='common_names',
          if_exists='replace', dtype={'common_names':types.VARCHAR(50)})
```

Table structure (pay attention at column names) in the MySQL DB:

[image]

**UPDATE:** I'd recommend you to flatten your MultiColumns before storing this DF into MySQL DB:

original columns:

```
In [266]: df.columns
Out[266]:
MultiIndex(levels=[['bloomberg', 'ft', 'index', 'investingcom'], ['', 'importance', 'original_name']],
           labels=[[3, 3, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2], [1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 0]])
```

let's flatten them:

```
In [267]: df.columns = ['{0[0]}__{0[1]}'.format(col) for col in df.columns]

In [268]: df.columns
Out[268]:
Index(['investingcom__importance', 'investingcom__original_name', 'bloomberg__importance', 'bloomberg__original_name', 'ft__importance',
       'ft__original_name', 'index__'],
      dtype='object')

In [272]: df.rename_axis('common_names') \
            .to_sql('zzz', engine, index=True, index_label='common_names',
                    if_exists='replace', dtype={'common_names':types.VARCHAR(50)})
```

How does it look in the MySQL DB:

```
mysql> select common_names, investingcom__importance, investingcom__original_name from zzz;
+-----------------------------------+--------------------------+-----------------------------------------+
| common_names                      | investingcom__importance | investingcom__original_name             |
+-----------------------------------+--------------------------+-----------------------------------------+
| ADP Employment Change             |                        3 | ADP Nonfarm Employment Change           |
| Building Permits                  |                        3 | Building Permits                        |
| Business Inventories MoM          |                        2 | Business Inventories (MoM)              |
| CPI Ex Food and Energy MoM        |                        3 | Core CPI (MoM)                          |
| Capacity Utilization              |                     NULL | NULL                                    |
| Chicago PMI                       |                        2 | Chicago PMI                             |
| Construction Spending MoM         |                     NULL | NULL                                    |
| Durable Goods Orders              |                        2 | Durable Goods Orders (MoM)              |
| Empire Manufacturing              |                     NULL | NULL                                    |
| Employment Cost Index             |                        2 | Employment Cost Index (QoQ)             |
| Existing Home Sales               |                        3 | Existing Home Sales                     |
| Existing Home Sales MoM           |                        2 | Existing Home Sales (MoM)               |
| FHFA House Price Index MoM        |                     NULL | NULL                                    |
| FOMC Rate Decision                |                        3 | Fed Interest Rate Decision              |
| Factory Orders                    |                        2 | Factory Orders (MoM)                    |
| GDP Price Index                   |                        2 | GDP Price Index (QoQ)                   |
| Housing Starts                    |                        2 | Housing Starts                          |
| ISM Non-Manufacturing PMI         |                        3 | ISM Non-Manufacturing PMI               |
| Import Price Index MoM            |                        2 | Import Price Index (MoM)                |
| Initial Jobless Claims            |                        2 | Initial Jobless Claims                  |
| Markit Composite PMI              |                        2 | Markit Composite PMI                    |
| New Home Sales                    |                        3 | New Home Sales                          |
| Nonfarm Payrolls                  |                        3 | Nonfarm Payrolls                        |
| PCE Core MoM                      |                        2 | Core PCE Price Index (MoM)              |
| Pending Home Sales MoM            |                        3 | Pending Home Sales (MoM)                |
| Personal Spending                 |                        2 | Personal Spending (MoM)                 |
| S&P/CaseShiller 20-City Index NSA |                        2 | S&P;/CS HPI Composite - 20 n.s.a. (YoY) |
| Total Net TIC Flows               |                        2 | TIC Net Long-Term Transactions          |
+-----------------------------------+--------------------------+-----------------------------------------+
28 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: no  I receive `ValueError: The type of common_names is not a SQLAlchemy type` It's also said on the page that I referenced above  that `String` is the sqlachemy syntax for VARCHAR. I also now tried `'sqlalchemy.types.String(25)'` but without succes

Comment: No still doesnt work. I also tried `sqlachemy.types.String(25)`, `sqlachemy.types.Text(25)` but it is still saying i am using an index without a key length

Comment: Did you have a time to have a look? I looked some more into the sqlalchemy docu and watch couples of tutos, but its still isn't clearer...

Comment: @jimbasquiat, i've found a solution for you - please check updated answer

Comment: @jimbasquiat, did it help?

Comment: Hi Thanks! Now I am not receiving error messages anymore. However the `"common_names"` index column is created in the db, but is filled with `null` values. Additionaly I have to use `sqlalchemy.types.VARCHAR(50)` (where you have `types.VARCHAR(50)` else I also receive an error message.

Comment: `NameError: name 'types' is not defined`.. To me it makes sense that I have to add the module name at the top. Else I could do `from sqlalchemy import *`, maybe that is what you are doing? Anyway this is not really a probelm , I think, the real problem is the empty `"common_names"` column! Have you checked it gets filled in your case?

Comment: OK yes I hadn't paid attention to `from sqlalchemy import types, create_engine` in your answer... So that's quite clear, however the values in the `common_names` column are still `null` !

Comment: @jimbasquiat, can you test it using you sample DF (from your question) - it works just fine for me...

Comment: U Oh yeah you'rt, when I reconstruct the dict with what I posted in the question it does work! Very strange... I checked the data type for both my original df index and the one from the question and they are both string... I can't see what goes wrong

Comment: The only difference I see is that when I type `ind_concat.index` with the original df it goes like `Index(['10-Year Note Auction', ......
      dtype='object', name='common_names', length=137)` when with the reconstructed df it is `Index(['10-Year Note Auction', ......
      dtype='object', name='common_names')` (i.e. `length` is not there at the end...)

Comment: check your columns - are they MultiLevel columns or like those from your sample data set?

Comment: Yes true with the reconstructed df it is not multilevel animore... In the original df it is, hence the columns named ('...','...'). In my original df, yes it is multilevel.

Comment: This might cause problems... I'd suggest to flatten your columns before saving it to SQL ...

Comment: Hmm ok... thanks! -- How do you flatten the columns?